# Draft questions lost forever

Tags: support, status-completed, user-interface

I just spent three hours constructing an very long and comprehensive answer -- and then my internet connection dropped (the perils of living on rural England).

Is there anyway to resuscitate my response (I'm not going to spend 3 hours on the task) or is it lost forever.?

Comment: This Meta SE Q&A suggests that there may be some hope: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting. Hopefully, you will not be stymied by "Drafts are not supported on self-answer.".

Comment: This won't help for your lost answer, but an option for the future might be to use something offline, like MarkdownPad2, then copy and paste the answer once you are done. http://markdownpad.com/news/2013/introducing-markdownpad-2/

Comment: @polygeo Hasn't worked for me. It easn't a self-anser, but it still vanished without trace.

Comment: I cannot remember whether I've ever seen it work.  I think I may have on occasion, but I also think that I have seen no draft available much more often.  I tend to just use Notepad to write drafts of posts longer than I am willing to risk to my flaky browser/graphics card combination.

Comment: I know I've part-written an answer before, then navigated away, and on returning found the draft still there. But I just tested it (only wrote a couple of lines then left the page) and it didn't work. Tried again, left it longer, and saw "draft saved" under the answer field, and did recover the draft on return. @PolyGeo's link notes there is only one "answer" draft (per user?) which is cleared on sumbission of _any_ answer. And if you had more than one answer field active, I'm not sure which one would get to save the draft.

Comment: @PolyGeo Can you advised what feature has been implemented or bug fixed to warrant a status-completed tag? As far as I can tell the problem still exists.

Comment: It's set to Status Completed because https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting is set to Status Completed.  This is not functionality that we can control from G&FH SE, but if you think the Meta SE Q&A has the wrong status feel free to raise it there.

Comment: @PolyGeo that question was marked as status-completed 6 years before this question was opened! But I'm not going to die in a ditch over it.

Answer (score 4):

This Meta SE Q&A suggests that there may be some hope: [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting).

Hopefully, you will not be stymied by "Drafts are not supported on self-answer."

I cannot remember whether I've ever seen it work. I think I may have on occasion, but I also think that I have seen no draft available much more often. I tend to just use Notepad to write drafts of posts longer than I am willing to risk to my flaky browser/graphics card combination.

[@AndyW has reported some success](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3187/draft-questions-lost-forever#comment5421_3187) in some circumstances (but not others):

> I know I've part-written an answer before, then navigated away, and on
>   returning found the draft still there. But I just tested it (only
>   wrote a couple of lines then left the page) and it didn't work. Tried
>   again, left it longer, and saw "draft saved" under the answer field,
>   and did recover the draft on return.